# „Sigmar Gabriel blockiert“. Ist „blockiert“ Partizip oder Präsens?

Tags: conjugation

Kann man ohne Kontext sagen, ob *blockiert* in der Schlagzeile

> Sigmar Gabriel blockiert

eigentlich Partizip oder dritte Person Präsens ist?

(Auch wenn man weiß, wer der Mann ist, bräuchte man vielleicht mehr Information?)

Comment: In dem Fall eher Präsens. In "Neuer Gesetzentwurf blockiert" eher Partizip.

Comment: @Eller aber man braucht doch einen Kontext? Oder ist es euch Muttersprachlern automatisch deutlich?

Comment: "Sigmar Gabriel" und "neuer Gesetzentwurf" sind Kontexte :)

Comment: Sollte die Frage nicht *Aktiv oder Passiv* lauten? Es gibt ja auch ein Partizip Präsens...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Antwort lautet nein.

Ohne Kontext sind beide Möglichkeiten gegeben:

1. Dritte Person Präsens: Sigmar Gabriel blockiert [irgendetwas/irgendjemanden].
2. Partizip: Sigmar Gabriel [ist durch irgendetwas/irgendjemanden] blockiert.

Beides wird häufig in Schlagzeilen verwendet. Für mein Sprachgefühl als Muttersprachler sind beide Möglichkeiten absolut gleichwertig zu betrachten und definitiv möglich.

Comment: Es gibt noch eine zweite Interpretation für die dritte Person Präsens, denn "blockieren" kann auch intransitiv sein.

Comment: @Em1: Kannst du das genauer erläutern? Natürlich ist "Sigmar Gabriel blockiert." ein vollständiger Satz mit intransitiv verwendetem *blockiert*, aber an der Interpretation, dass er jemanden oder etwas anderen blockiert (der oder das bei der intransitiven Verwendung einfach nicht genannt wird), ändert das nichts.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Bei der intransitiven Verwendung ist nicht "der oder das" weggelassen, sondern es wäre sogar falsch. Denn es wird _nicht_ jemand  oder etwas blockiert, sondern die Person blockiert einfach. Sie bockt. Macht zu. Verschließt sich.

Comment: @Em1: Sie bockt. Macht zu. Verschließt sich. Gegenüber anderen. Die dann folglich blockiert werden. Es ist unsinnig, von "blockieren" zu sprechen, wenn dieses Blockieren keine Auswirkung auf andere Akteure hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Wenn du das so siehst. Es ist trotzdem was anderes, als wenn man jemanden "aktiv" blockiert. Stelle ich mich dir in den Weg, blockiere ich dich. Du wirst mich wegschubsen, damit du durchkommst. Blockiere ich jedoch nur, ist's dir scheiß egal.

Comment: @Em1: "Blockiere ich jedoch nur, ist's dir scheiß egal." - nicht, wenn dadurch irgendeiner meiner Pläne durchkreuzt wird. Ich kann mir ehrlich keinen konkreten Kontext vorstellen, in dem jemand bockiert, und dadurch aber nicht auch irgendjemanden oder irgendetwas, zumindest sich selber, blockiert.

Answer (score 3):

Ich könnte ohne Kontext nicht sagen, ob Sigmar Gabriel durch irgendeinen Umstand blockiert ist, oder ob er irgendetwas blockiert.

Answer (score 1):

Eindeutig nein. Hier sind zwei (einhalb) mögliche Ergänzungen, wobei ich wie meine Vorredner feststellen muss, dass ich beide prinzipiell für gleich wahrscheinlich halte:

> Umgestürzter Baum im Harz. **Sigmar Gabriel**s Auto **blockiert.**
>
> Mautgesetz soll kommen. **Sigmar Gabriel blockiert** es.
>
> Mautgesetz soll kommen aber **Sigmar Gabriel blockiert.**

Das letzte Beispiel soll nur klarstellen, dass *blockieren* sowohl transitiv als auch intransitiv verwendet werden kann.

---

Vielleicht etwas offensichtlicher ist die Zweideutigkeit wenn anstelle eines deutschen Politikers der US-Präsident Subjekt der Überschrift ist. Oftmals wird dieser in seiner politischen Handlungsfähigkeit von einem Kongress, in dem die Gegenpartei die Mehrheit besitzt, blockiert. Andererseits ist er sehr wohl auch in der Lage unliebsame Initiativen zu blockieren. Was die Zeitung damit sagen möchte, kann erst in der Unterzeile oder im Artikel klar werden.

Comment: Aber deine Beispiele zeigen doch auf, dass die Zeitungsüberschrift eindeutig ist.

Comment: @deponensvogel Finde ich nicht. Wenn die Überschrift »Sigmar Gabriel blockiert« und die Unterzeile »Umgestürzter Baum verhindert die Weiterfahrt des Vizekanzlers« lauten, ist eindeutig die erste Variante gemeint, auch wenn ich, um sie in einem Satz unterzubringen, ein Zwischenwort eingefügt habe.

Comment: Wiedermal ein konstruiertes Beispiel. Es gibt zig Zeitungsüberschriften, wo irgendwer intransitiv herumblockiert. Würde Gabriel wirklich von einem umgestürzten Baum im Zaum gehalten, würde hingegen keiner ›Sigmar Gabriel blockiert‹ schreiben.

Comment: @deponensvogel Ach, dann ersetze doch einfach *Sigmar Gabriel* durch *Präsident Obama.* Wie oft dieser vom Kongress blockiert wurde …

Answer (score 1):

Im Prinzip gebe ich den Vorantworten recht, es ist nicht ohne impliziten Kontext unterscheidbar, allerdings ist es für einen Politiker äußerst ungewöhnlich blockiert zu sein, er versucht es möglichst zu vermeiden blockiert zu sein/werden und es schadet seiner Karriere. Deshalb blockiert er in der Regel etwas. Diese Erfahrung hat ein politikinteressierter Muttersprachler durchaus und wird bei solch einer Schlagzeile wohl eher an den Präsens denken.

Ausnahmen bestätigen die Regel: Witzigerweise wurde gerade Gabriel jüngst durch Gerichte blockiert, als er die Tengelmann-Übernahme ermächtigen wollte, aber ich persönlich denke zuerst, daß ein Politiker eher aktiv blockiert als blockiert wird.

Comment: "allerdings ist es für einen Politiker äußerst ungewöhnlich blockiert zu sein" - selbst, wenn das so wäre: Genau deshalb wäre es ja eine Schlagzeile.

Answer (score -3):

›Blockiert‹ ist hier eindeutig ein Verb im Präsens, und ich bin mir auch sicher, dass das jeder Muttersprachler, der sich nicht zu viel kluge Gedanken macht, sofort versteht.

Wie soll man sich das vorstellen? Gabriel ist blockiert?

Als Spitzenpolitiker tut man nichts lieber, als Initiativen des Koalitionspartners zu blockieren. So ist es also doppelt narrensicher, dass mit ›blockiert‹ das Verb und nicht das Partizip gemeint ist.

Comment: Du konstruierst hierbei einen Kontext, der nicht existiert.

Comment: Gebe dir durchaus Recht, siehe auch meine Antwort, allerdings sind solche verkürzten Schlagzeilen knackig und üblich: Gabriel schockiert, Gabriel irritiert, Gabriel verwirrt, also auch denkbar: Gabriel blockiert. Also narrensicher ist es mitnichten.

Comment: Aus deinem abschließenden Beispiel folgt genau das Gegenteil von dem, was du behauptest. Wenn man als Spitzenpolitiker andere Politiker blockiert, ist es genauso gut möglich, dass in einer gegebenen Meldung <Politiker X> jemand anderen blockiert wie dass er blockiert wird oder ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper IMHO, gibt es für Muttersprachler durchaus Tendenzen beim Lesen von Überschriften im Zusammenhang mit dem Subjekt, teste mal, woran denkst du: 1. Merkel schockiert, 2. Gauck ermahnt, 3. Böhmermann verärgert

1:A,2:B,3:B
A:Präsens,B:Partizip
Richtig?

Comment: @Thomas: Mein spontaner erster Eindruck war: 1B, 2A, 3B. Zum Beispiel: Merkel ist schockiert über den Wahlausgang, Gauck ermahnt die Konfliktparteien, sich friedlich zu einigen und Böhmermann ist verärgert über das aus dem Kontext Reißen seines Gedichts. In jedem Fall kann ich mir aber ohne langes Nachdenken auch die umgekehrte Interpretation vorstellen - Merkel schockiert durch Unterstützung von Zensurbestrebungen, Gauck wird von <Autokrat X> ermahnt, sich aus internen Angelegenheiten fremder Länder herauszuhalten, Böhmermann verärgert durch provokante Formulierung.